# Add tick marks to jQuery slider?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, slider

How do I add tick marks to the jQuery slider? Say I have values from 1 to 10, how I can I add a tick at each value?

I've seen similar posts on S.O. but they all suggest plug-ins, and I would like to hard code it due to a lot of interactivity with other elements.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Similar to this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435437/how-do-i-add-a-marker-to-a-jquery-ui-slider).  The answer from Mortimer might help.

Although there is no official way of doing it yet, it'd be nice to have it baked in the jQuery UI slider.

Comment: @DonnyP: Mando was specifically calling your attention to Mortimer's Answer, not Bijan's

Answer (score 17):

Thanks Code-Toad. I modified your code to work with percents instead of pixels, so now it's immune to window-resize:

Javascript:

```
function setSliderTicks(){
    var $slider =  $('#slider');
    var max =  $slider.slider("option", "max");    
    var spacing =  100 / (max -1);

    $slider.find('.ui-slider-tick-mark').remove();
    for (var i = 0; i < max ; i++) {
        $('<span class="ui-slider-tick-mark"></span>').css('left', (spacing * i) +  '%').appendTo($slider); 
     }
}
```

CSS:

```
.ui-slider-tick-mark{
    display:inline-block;
    width:2px;
    background:black;
    height:16px;
    position:absolute;
    top:-4px;
}
```

Comment: .ui-slider-tick-mark {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 2px;
    background: #fcf8e3;
    height: 28px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}
If you want the styles to appear at the bottom. This is a mod of your code. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks Arie Livshin and CodeToad. The previous code assume that the min value is always 1. I edited the code to work with min values too.

```
$("#users-slider").slider(
  {
    range: "min",
    value: 3,
    min: 3,
    max: 6,
    create: function( event, ui ) {
      setSliderTicks(event.target);
    },
  }
);

function setSliderTicks(el) {
    var $slider =  $(el);
    var max =  $slider.slider("option", "max");    
    var min =  $slider.slider("option", "min");    
    var spacing =  100 / (max - min);

    $slider.find('.ui-slider-tick-mark').remove();
    for (var i = 0; i < max-min ; i++) {
        $('<span class="ui-slider-tick-mark"></span>').css('left', (spacing * i) +  '%').appendTo($slider); 
     }
}
```

Comment: you may want to change the loop to start from i=1. this makes ui look better in my opinion

Comment: Use `i <= max-min` to show last tick mark.

Answer (score 4):

here is a simple solution assuming that slider interval = 1.

```
function setSliderTicks(){
    var $slider =  $('#slider');
    var max =  $slider.slider("option", "max");    
    var spacing =  $slider.width() / (max -1);

    $slider.find('.ui-slider-tick-mark').remove();
        for (var i = 0; i < max ; i++) {
            $('<span class="ui-slider-tick-mark"></span>').css('left', (spacing * i) + 'px').appendTo($slider);                    
        }
}


.ui-slider-tick-mark{
display:inline-block;
width:2px;
background:black;
height:16px;
position:absolute;
top:-4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a background image that has the marks in the right places - this would probably be the simplest way.

Comment: The range of the slider is dynamic, so using a background image won't work. Thanks though. I suspect there are CSS solutions