# Add ticks to Slider UI

Tags: jquery-ui, slider, jquery-ui-slider

I'm fairly javascript and jquery. I'm trying to add a slider to my webpage. It's a basic slider where anyone can select a value between 0-100. I'm not sure how to mark SOME intervals in the middle.

This is the code i have so far

```
  <script>
    $(function() {
    var temp = 0;
        $( "#slider" ).slider({
            animate: true,
            value:temp,
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            step: 1,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#amount" ).val(ui.value );
            },
            stop: function(event, ui) {          
                temp = ui.value;
                //Do something
            }
        });
        $( "#amount" ).val($( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
    });
    </script>
```

It is functioning properly. What i wanna try to do is add interval markers at 0.25,50,75 and 100.

I have gone through a few questions on SO but not sure how to proceed with the implementation. Would appreciate the help.

I tried this implementation: http://jsbin.com/iwime but this is not what i am trying to do as i just want the ticks to appear at those regular intervals but users shold stll be able to select other values.

Thanks
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want something like this: http://jsbin.com/iwime/116

So, instead of using the number of ticks in the `max` option of slider, you use whatever max units you want to provide, e.g. 100. Then in `refershTicks()`, update the algorithm to toggle the class.

Slider settings:

```
    var slider = $("#slider").slider({
        ...
        max: 100,     // the only change
        ...
    });
```

And the `refreshTicks()` method:

```
    function refreshTicks() {
        var s = slider
            , lo = s.slider("values", 0), hi = s.slider("values", 1);
        var max = s.slider('option', 'max');
        s.find(".tick").each(function(i) {
            var i = (i + 1) * (max/ticks.length) - (max/ticks.length)/2;   // the updated algorithm
            var inRange = (i >= lo && i < hi);
            $(this)
                [(inRange ? 'add' : 'remove') + 'Class']("ui-widget-header")
                [(inRange ? 'remove' : 'add') + 'Class']("ui-widget-content");
        });
    }
```

Comment: Yes this is what i'm looking for but i do not want a range slider all i want is like a one directional slider. Like a volume control.

Comment: I'm not sure how to change this slider to what i want.

Answer (score 0):

[Similar to this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435437/how-do-i-add-a-marker-to-a-jquery-ui-slider) : The answer from Bijan might help.

The implementation of jQuery UI slider he suggest may help you to find a solution:
http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_jquery_ui_slider_from_a_select_element_now_with_aria_support/